# Missing icons on Qt 5.12

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, qtlocation

Until now I had used `mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-preview-night-v2` style, which was working fine. But when I changed my style to "Navigation"(which is default template from Mapbox Studio), I got following warnings:

```
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [1]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [1]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
```

And my map does not have half of icons on it.
[image]

Comment: is the navigation style you are switching to a style you made yourself? Or is it one of the bundled styles? Also, what access token are you using?

Comment: @Pa_ Navigation style is official template(I left it unmodified), access token is mine, and it's okay. Btw [found](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16544) some issue closely related to mine.

Comment: it could be an outdated style in the plugin? Try to verify what's the latest navigation style, and pass it using additional_style_ids plugin parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work had to replace

```
["get", "filterrank"]
["get", "sizerank"]
["get", "symbolrank"]
["get", "len"]
["get", "reflen"]
["get", "layer"]
```

in filters with

```
["to-number", ["get", "filterrank"]]
etc...
```

Comment: In what filters? where: in QML or mapbox studio? Could You provide full code in the question and in answer?

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich in mapbox studio